# How to concatenate 2 columns and keep text styling with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have several columns that I need to concatenante, while the text styling for one column is kept intact and each column is concatenated in a new line (carriage return).

*Col A* text in bold, *Col B* text normal, *Col C* = concatenated col A content **in bold** + carriage return + col B content.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/HtEFM7D.png]

Using Concatenate formula in combination with CHAR(10) works but obviously the text styling isn't kept. VBA seems to be the way to go but I'm a total newbie at it.

I found the following code that does the concatenation, kees the styling but for the life of me I cant figure how to include a carriage return with vbCrLf in a string.

```
Sub MergeFormatCell()
    Dim xSRg As Range
    Dim xDRg As Range
    Dim xRgEachRow As Range
    Dim xRgEach As Range
    Dim xRgVal As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xRgLen As Integer
    Dim xSRgRows As Integer
    Dim xAddress As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xSRg = Application.InputBox("Select cell columns to concatenate:", "Concatenate in Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    If xSRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xSRgRows = xSRg.Rows.Count
    Set xDRg = Application.InputBox("Select cells to output the result:", "Concatenate in Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xDRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xDRg = xDRg(1)
    For I = 1 To xSRgRows
        xRgLen = 1
        With xDRg.Offset(I - 1)
            .Value = vbNullString
            .ClearFormats
            Set xRgEachRow = xSRg(1).Offset(I - 1).Resize(1, xSRg.Columns.Count)
            For Each xRgEach In xRgEachRow
                .Value = .Value & Trim(xRgEach.Value) & " "
            Next
            For Each xRgEach In xRgEachRow
                xRgVal = xRgEach.Value
                With .Characters(xRgLen, Len(Trim(xRgVal))).Font
                .Name = xRgEach.Font.Name
                .FontStyle = xRgEach.Font.FontStyle
                .Size = xRgEach.Font.Size
                .Strikethrough = xRgEach.Font.Strikethrough
                .Superscript = xRgEach.Font.Superscript
                .Subscript = xRgEach.Font.Subscript
                .OutlineFont = xRgEach.Font.OutlineFont
                .Shadow = xRgEach.Font.Shadow
                .Underline = xRgEach.Font.Underline
                .ColorIndex = xRgEach.Font.ColorIndex
                End With
                xRgLen = xRgLen + Len(Trim(xRgVal)) + 1
            Next
        End With
    Next I
End Sub
```

The interest of the above code is that it allows the user to specify via an input box the cells range to concatenate and where to output the results.

Anyone can give me a hand and modify it so each new column goes in a new line after concatenation?

If you got a simplier solution I'm all for it as long as it works.
p.s. I'm running Excel 2013 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code does not copy formatting, but it is concatenate both columns and bold the value appears in column A.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Row = 1 To LastRow

            With .Range("C" & Row)
                .Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Row).Value & vbNewLine & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Row).Value
                .Characters(1, Len(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Row).Value)).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
            End With

        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

**EDITED VERSION:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long
    Dim strA As String, strB As String, strC As String, strD As String, strE As String, strF As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Row = 1 To LastRow

            strA = .Range("A" & Row).Value
            strB = .Range("B" & Row).Value
            strC = .Range("C" & Row).Value
            strD = .Range("D" & Row).Value
            strE = .Range("E" & Row).Value
            strF = .Range("F" & Row).Value

            With .Range("G" & Row)

                .Value = strA & vbNewLine & strB & vbNewLine & strC & vbNewLine & strD & vbNewLine & strE & vbNewLine & strF
                .Characters(1, Len(strA)).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Characters((Len(strA) + Len(strB) + 5), Len(strC)).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Characters((Len(strA) + Len(strB) + Len(strC) + Len(strD) + 9), Len(strE)).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"

            End With

        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great :) It works under the condition that Text in Col A is not originally styled in bold. Thank you!

Comment: to push things a little further; how would this code be modified if instead of 2 columns I had 4 where; A and C being the "headers" and B end D their corresponding content ?

Comment: Upload an image of the data and an image of the output you want to make things clear.

Comment: You just saved my day!